# Windows Store app, Listview Groupheaderplacement Left and vertical scrolling

Tags: xaml, listview, windows-store-apps, grouping

So I'm having a issue with GroupHeaderPlacement and Vertical scrolling. 
What Im trying to achieve is this: [image]

But for some reason my groups are getting arranged in a horisontal scrolling direction. Anyone know if I'm missing something obvious here or if you simple can't have a vertical scrolling Listview if you have GroupHeaderPlacement Left.

The Code is:`<ListView x:Name="ItemsGridView" 
                          Margin="118,-5,0,0" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource AllCurrentGroup}}" 
                          SelectionMode="Single" 
                          Grid.Row="2" 
                          Grid.Column="0"
                          ShowsScrollingPlaceholders="False"
                          SelectionChanged="SelectedPresentationItem_SelectionChanged" 
                          IsSwipeEnabled="True">
            <ListView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid GroupHeaderPlacement="Left" Orientation="Vertical" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemsPanel>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="1"  Height="80" Margin="40,0,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Tid }" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" >
                                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource Orange}"/>
                                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                                    </TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Titel }" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Grid.Column="1" />
                                </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="{Binding Rows}" Width="160" Height="200">
                                    <StackPanel.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="{StaticResource BlueDark}"/>
                                    </StackPanel.Background>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Vecka, Converter={StaticResource ToWeekString }}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="20,13,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Datum, Converter={StaticResource ToDayNumber }}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="20,26,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Datum, Converter={StaticResource ToMonth }}" Style="{StaticResource SubheaderTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="20,-3,0,0"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding  Datum, Converter={StaticResource ToDayString }}" Style="{StaticResource BodyTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" FontFamily="Global User Interface" Margin="20,13,0,0"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <WrapGrid Orientation="Vertical"></WrapGrid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </ListView.GroupStyle>
        </ListView>`

Comment: I think there is a piece of code missing in your post. Can't see the beginning of the ListView XAML declaration

Comment: Sorry about that, fixed it now. So entire code is visible.

Answer (score 0):

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/GroupedGridView-77c59e8e/sourcecode?fileId=44751&pathId=298223712

Please refer the above sample link which helps you to achieve your req.

Comment: Actually looked trough that example and havnt seen anything that really helps.